# sorting via order by and row_number via user variable in mariadb

Tags: mysql, variables, sql-order-by, mariadb, temp-tables

I've read that any order by Operation is done at the end of the query and therefore sorting cannot be forced in a result before.

So what I'm trying to achive is to get only one record from a result with duplicates by using variables which assign row numbers and by using a having-clause I only select the first row.

Sorry for my bad explanation, I hope you know what I mean by taking a look at this:

```
select *
from address left join
(select address.add_nr as add_nr, acc.typ as typ, acc.seq as seq,
@num := if(@add_nr = address.add_nr, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,  
@add_nr := address.add_nr as dummy
from 
address left join


(

select con_add_nr as add_nr, 'XY' as typ, 1 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet
where con_pol_kz IN('L')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
group by 1,2,3

union
select ris_add_nr as add_nr, 'XX' as typ, 4 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet,risaddress
where con_pol_kz IN('P','PU','A')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
and con_nr=ris_con_nr
and ris_art='VP'
group by 1,2,3


union
select ris_add_nr as add_nr, 'YY' as typ, 3 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet,risaddress
where con_pol_kz IN('P','PU','A')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
and vrs_nr=ris_vrs_nr
and ris_art='VP'
group by 1,2,3


union
select ris_add_nr as add_nr, 'YX' as typ, 5 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet,risaddress
where con_pol_kz IN('P','PU','A')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
and con_nr=ris_con_nr
and ris_art='2. VN'
group by 1,2,3


union
select ris_add_nr as add_nr, 'X' as typ, 2 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet,risaddress
where con_pol_kz IN('P','PU','A')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
and vrs_nr=ris_vrs_nr
and ris_art='2. VN'
group by 1,2,3

order by add_nr,seq asc) as acc on acc.add_nr=address.add_nr
having row_number=1) as acc on address.add_nr=acc.add_nr;
```

So the problem is that the order by Operation is done at the end when the row_number has already been assumed. What I need is to sort the result  by the sequence number "seq" first, achieving that the first entry gets row_number=1. At the moment the first entry in the "unsorted" Result gets the row_number=1 and this is not what I need.

Comment: Please reformulate as `JOIN...ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `HAVING` with columns that you're generating on the fly with a user variable. MySQL performs some optimizations that mess this up. Instead, use a `WHERE` clause in the outer query.

```
select *
from address left join
(select address.add_nr as add_nr, acc.typ as typ, acc.seq as seq,
@num := if(@add_nr = address.add_nr, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,  
@add_nr := address.add_nr as dummy
from 
address 
cross join (select @add_nr := 0, @num := 0) AS init
left join


(

select con_add_nr as add_nr, 'XY' as typ, 1 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet
where con_pol_kz IN('L')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
group by 1,2,3

union
select ris_add_nr as add_nr, 'XX' as typ, 4 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet,risaddress
where con_pol_kz IN('P','PU','A')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
and con_nr=ris_con_nr
and ris_art='VP'
group by 1,2,3


union
select ris_add_nr as add_nr, 'YY' as typ, 3 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet,risaddress
where con_pol_kz IN('P','PU','A')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
and vrs_nr=ris_vrs_nr
and ris_art='VP'
group by 1,2,3


union
select ris_add_nr as add_nr, 'YX' as typ, 5 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet,risaddress
where con_pol_kz IN('P','PU','A')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
and con_nr=ris_con_nr
and ris_art='2. VN'
group by 1,2,3


union
select ris_add_nr as add_nr, 'X' as typ, 2 as seq
from conctract,conctractdet,risaddress
where con_pol_kz IN('P','PU','A')
and con_nr=vrs_con_nr
and cond_spa_nr IN (102,160,173)
and vrs_nr=ris_vrs_nr
and ris_art='2. VN'
group by 1,2,3

order by add_nr,seq asc) as acc on acc.add_nr=address.add_nr) as acc on address.add_nr=acc.add_nr
WHERE row_number = 1;
```

This optimization is briefly alluded to in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html)

> `HAVING` is merged with `WHERE` if you do not use `GROUP BY` or aggregate functions (`COUNT()`, `MIN()`, and so on).

What this means is if it can treat the `HAVING` clause like `WHERE`, it will do so, so it will remove rows from the results while generating the result set, instead of waiting until all the result rows are produced.

Comment: It seems like the `GROUP BY` on each select is totally useless. ??

Comment: It could be simplified to `group by add_nr`, since `typ` and `seq` are the same in each subquery in the union. We don't know enough about the data to  tell whether this is needed or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the result is now correct. Is there any place where I can read more about the having-optimizations? Just for information: The group by is needed otherwise I would get multiple rows from each query in the union-block.

Comment: I'm not sure it's documented well, it's just something I've discovered when trying to use it.

Comment: I found something about it in the manual, I've added it to the answer.

Comment: ok now I've found something strange: If I open a new connection and execute my query, the row_number is always returned as "1" and therefore I get multiple rows per address. BUT: If I execute the same query the second time, I will get the correct result. If I disconnect and connect again, the result will be wrong. What is going on here? How can I stop this strange behaviour?

Comment: Variables like `@num` persist between queries on a connection. You need to set it back to `0` before the query. A common way to do this in one step is to add a join with a subquery that initializes all the variables: `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @num := 0, @add_nr := NULL) AS init`

Comment: Ok now its clear that the variables persist. But I do not understand the difference between the first and the second run of the query. The row_number generated via the num variable is depending on the value of add_nr. Am I wright that the if(@add_nr=address.add_nr..... is checked in every row? If so, it should increment num otherwise num is 1. I dont understand why num is in the first run always 1...

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that you reset `@num` to `1` every time `add_nr` changes. I suspect the problem is related to `@add_nr` not being initialized before the first query. But I don't understand why the assignment on the first row doesn't clear that up. Best practice is to always initialize the variables.

Comment: I've added the `CROSS JOIN` that initializes the variables.

Comment: I'm afraid its still not working. You are right that there seems to be a problem with @add_nr not being initialized and the cross join doesn't solve the problem. So if I first of all execute:

set @add_nr=0;
set @num=0;

and then execute my query, it will work - of course. But the Problem is that my Application doesn't use persistent connections and for certain reasons I don't want to change that. So do you see another solution for initializing the variables within the same query?

Comment: You don't need to use persistent connections, that would only be needed if you needed to keep counting something from one query to the next. Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Ok, I will try to make a sqlfiddle. Just for making sure: if i execute my query 2 times within the same connection, the result is fine. Closing and opening a new connection,  causes a wrong result. So @add_nr is affected by the first run of the query

Comment: Ok unfortunatly the demo Data for sqlfiddle is not returning the same behaviour. BUT: I've looked a little bit deeper into the situation: For me it looks like that there is a problem with the if (). Its definitly the if which returns "false" in the first run allthough the result should be true. Is it possible that there is a problem with type converting?

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug in MariaDB. I've only used real MySQL.

Comment: No it's not, I've tried it in MySQL 5.6 and its the same in green. But I have asked myself why the if always returns false in the first run. The only thing which looks logical to me is the reason that add_nr has not been initialized when the first if() is executed and therefore mysql doesn't run the if again because it is not expecting that add_nr is initialized later. So what I did was just moving the block with the cross join to another place and now it's working. But it would be nice to understand why it didn't work until now.

Comment: That may be possible. I've always put the subquery that initializes the variables after the subquery that uses them. This time I put it first, because the subquery that uses them is a LEFT JOIN. But maybe it's actually executing the queries from the bottom up, so the variable isn't initialized yet.